# Threejs: glb file reflect the environment but not itself

Tags: reflection, three.js, raytracing

In threejs, I successfully import and display a glb file of a house (the house has two floors and various objects on each floor, among which chairs, some tables, a kitchen etc, such as a real house). My problem is that I am able to make the house and its objects reflect the environmental light but I am not able to make the objects of the house reflect themselves. My ultimate goal would be to implement some real time ray-tracing, but at this point I would be happy to only generate some real time reflections which in addition to the environmental light also reflect the other objects of the house. Same with shadows.

I have not found anything online about it this type of reflections. Does anyone know a good place where to start? Or if you have faced a similar challange, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`CubeCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/CubeCamera) to render the scene with the environment including the objects to be in the reflection. Then you pass that resulting texture to the `.envMap` property to the object(s) that you want to show those reflections. The only problem with this is that if you have many objects that show other objects in the reflections, you'll need a huge amount of cubeCamera renders, each one from the position of that object.

[See this working demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic), it only captures one reflection pass as I described above, from the position of the sphere. You can kind of see the knot has a reflection of itself, which isn't realistic, but it isn't very noticeable. It's a tradeoff.

You could also copy [the mirror demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_mirror) if you only have a few planes that act as mirrors.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I knew about the CubeCamera to generate realistic reflections, the problem is that I have a single glb file with many geometries in it and it does not seem that I can assign a CubeCamera to each, since they seem to be evaluated as a single object - the house. If I were building a house from scratch in threejs, your answer would have been perfect, but I have a glb file and as I said everything seem to only reflect environmental light. I hope I was able to explain my self; and I wonder if you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Screen Space Reflections, or SSR. It has not yet been implemented in three.js See here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8248